# Filtrar los registros en un array jsonb en postgres

Tags: postgresql

Tengo una tabla en Postgres con un campo jsonb donde se guarda un array de json:

TABLA PURCHASES

| id | purchaser | items_purchased |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Bob | [{"name": "Dell 123 Laptop Computer", "price": 1300, "productid": 1}, {"name": "Mechanical Keyboard", "price": 120, "productid": 2}] |
| 2 | Carol | [{"name": "Virtual Keyboard", "price": 150, "productid": 3}, {"name": "Dell 123 Laptop Computer", "price": 1300, "productid": 1}, {"name": "LG Ultrawide Monitor", "price": 190, "productid": 8}] |
| 3 | Ted | [{"name": "Ergonomic Keyboard", "price": 90, "productid": 6}, {"name": "Dell 789 Desktop Computer", "price": 120, "productid": 7}] |
| 4 | Alice | [{"name": "Dell 789 Desktop Computer", "price": 120, "productid": 7}, {"name": "Mechanical Keyboard", "price": 120, "productid": 2}] |

Dado por ejemplo un *productid*, quiero obtener todos los registros donde se compró ese artículo. Por ejemplo, para el *productid = 1* busco esta salida:

| id | purchaser | items_purchased |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Bob | [{"name": "Dell 123 Laptop Computer", "price": 1300, "productid": 1}] |
| 2 | Carol | [{"name": "Dell 123 Laptop Computer", "price": 1300, "productid": 1}] |

Lo que he intentado es lo siguiente:

```
select * from purchases where (items_purchased->>'productid')::integer = 1;
```

pero me devuelve una tabla vacía.

También intenté

```
select * from purchases where
items_purchased @> ANY (ARRAY ['{"productid":1}']::jsonb[]);
```

obteniendo nuevamente una tabla vacía.

También intenté varias combinaciones del la siguiente consulta

```
select * from purchases, jsonb_array_elements(items_purchased) with ordinality arr(item_object, position) where items_purchased->>'productid'::integer = 1;
```

pero siempre obtengo errores de sintaxis o de conversión explícita de datos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finalmente encontré la manera de hacerlo con la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT o.obj, p.id, p.purchaser
FROM purchases p
CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(p.items_purchased) o(obj)
WHERE o.obj ->> 'productid' = '1';
```

Esta es la salida:

| obj | id | purchaser |
| --- | --- | --- |
| {"name": "Dell 123 Laptop Computer", "price": 1300, "productid": 1} | 1 | Bob |
| {"name": "Dell 123 Laptop Computer", "price": 1300, "productid": 1} | 2 | Carol |

(2 filas)

Comment: Interesante. Qué tipo de dato es la columna donde está el JSON?

Comment: Es del tipo jsonb. Igualmente en esa columna se guardan arrays de objetos

Answer (score 2):

Prueba usando `CAST`

```
select * 
from purchases 
where CAST(items_purchased->>'productid' AS INTEGER) = 1
```

Comment: También me devolvió una tabla vacía.